# How to use proxy in selenium chrome

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I need to use Selenium with http proxy with authorization

I'm trying to use the arguments:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("proxy-server='http://user:pass@1.1.1.1:8989'");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But I get an error in the browser `ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES`.

Then I tried to use the object `Proxy`:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

Proxy proxyOption = new Proxy();
proxyOption.setHttpProxy("1.1.1.1:8989");
options.setProxy(proxyOption);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The browser worked without error but did not use a proxy

Comment: I am facing same. @DimaTverdoy did you find any solution?